# Duration between two dates with or without momentjs

Tags: jquery, momentjs, bootstrap-table

I am trying to figure out how I can get the duration between two dates either with or without momentjs.

here is the code I have implemented in the table using bootstrap-table

```
<tr>
     <th id="startedat" data-field="StartedAt" data-formatter="dateFormatter">Started At</th>
     <th id="finishedat" data-field="FinishedAt" data-formatter="dateFormatter">Finished At</th>
     <th data-formatter="duration">Duration</th>
```

in my Javascript I would then use

```
function dateFormatter(value) {
    return moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
```

but how to do I now set up the function for duration? any ideas

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: [Moment `.diff()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Comment: thanks but I cannot seem to get that to work with "ids" nor with the date-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with moment You can use [.diff](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

```
  var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
  var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
  a.diff(b) // 86400000
```

Comment: looks promising thanks still have not figured out how to get the <tr> id to be use the date in the data-field any ideas?